# Scrollable grid in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have to implement a **scrollable grid** of images in Xamarin Forms, the grid is `n x 2`, so two images by side. Since I have no idea how to combine a `ScrollView` with a `Grid`, I tried this (all my controls are inside a grid, but this is not relevant):

```
<ScrollView x:Name="scroller"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            BackgroundColor="Fuchsia"
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
    <StackLayout x:Name="stacker">
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="test.png" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
            <Image Source="test.png" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <!-- put several of these here -->
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But the results are far from being acceptable:

[image: stack]

I have tried several variations, but it seems that `StackLayout` won't obey the boundaries of its parent.

Just for fun I've tried a `Grid` without any success since it adds **a lot of space** between the grids (and I don't know why):

```
<ScrollView x:Name="scroller"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            BackgroundColor="Fuchsia"
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
    <StackLayout x:Name="stacker">                    
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="test.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Image Source="test.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
        <!-- put several of these here --> 
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: grid]

How can I achieve a simple scrollable grid in Xamarin Forms? This is my hand-drawn objective:

[image: objective]

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: Grid probably isn't going to be the best option. You will end up doing a lot of heavy lifting in the view to make it appear as you wish. It might be easier with a ListView where you have a datatemplate.Take a look at [Two Columns per row in ListView](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42792/two-columns-per-row-in-listview)

Comment: @Neil What about just using an horizontal `StackLayout`? Is it possible to bound the size?

Comment: the isse with horizontal stacklayouts, if I am following correctly is. For example, there are 9 images that need to be displayed. Some code has to look at that and determine, 5 stacklayouts are needed. add those and add the images. than that code requires maintainence and so on... you see where I am going with this? Did you have a chance to look at the link? the example was laid out very nicely.

Comment: @Neil I am looking at that code and probably will use it. I don't think that code is that unmaintainable, it's just a for loop to add a stack layout and insert two images in it. I don't understand why the horizontal stack layout expands beyond its parent though...

Answer (score 1):

You should use a ListView for this task. Otherwise there is a lot things you have to deal on your own. Here is a link where I hope you find exactly the layout you want: https://github.com/02047788a/TwoColumnListView

Answer (score 0):

The spacing between the elements, is according to the StackLayout Spacing, which defines how each element added will be spaced.

Another thing you have to take into consideration are the VerticalOptions, which will decide the position of the elements, see the bellow example:

```
<ScrollView x:Name="scroller"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            BackgroundColor="Fuchsia"
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.RowSpan="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
    <StackLayout x:Name="stacker" VerticalOptions="Start" Padding="0" Spacing="0">                    
        <Grid VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="test.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Image Source="test.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        </Grid>
        <!-- put several of these here --> 
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the results here are the same for me. It adds a lot of spacing between the grids...

Comment: I don't think that will work since the number of images can be variable. so how many grids does he put in there at design time?